# WSE 3.0 using  x509 certificate for signing wcf message

Tags: .net, web-services, signing, x509, wse

Please can you please help to use x509 certificates for signing . I am using WSE 3.0 for visual sturio 2010 c#.

error message is 
{"WSE101: An asynchronous operation raised an exception."}

and inner exception message is 
{"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."}